# Crash on QDomNodeList usage. Qt5.1.1 Version

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt5

I am getting crash for the following code. I am using VS2012+including the Qt libraries/paths. What am I missing here?

```
QFile file(SomeFile); QDomDocument document; QDomElement root;
QString errmsg; int errorline; int errorColNo;        
if(!document.setContent(&file,false,&errmsg,&errorline,&errorColNo)) 
{
    QMessageBox::information(this,"Error", "Failed to load "+errmsg+"\nError Line: "+errorline+" , Error Column: "+errorColNo);
    return -1;
}
root = document.firstChildElement();
{
    //The below line causes crash. Basically when the scope ends, the destructor is getting called, and it gives an invalid heap pointer crash.
    QDomNodeList mylist= root.elementsByTagName("A");   
    // ... Some Code.
}
```

I do not see a crash if I directly use `root.elementsByTagName("A")` else were is the code.

Comment: Does it still crash if you remove "Some Code"?

Comment: yes, the call to destructor of mylist is causing the issue. but not sure why. basically end of scope on which dest is called. doesn't matter is "Some code" is there or not.

Comment: Could you put it into a self-contained single-file example? Instead of `QFile` use `QBuffer` and fill it from a string. That way, if it turnns out to be a Qt bug, there'll be a ready test case.